# How to show content in multiple lines automatically in auto layout or swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Here is part my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    userName.text = username!

    let current_status = Status!
    if current_status == "Online"
    {
        Suggestion.text = "He is Online! You can talk with him directly or add him!"

    }
    else
    {
        Suggestion.text = "He is busy! You'd better talk with him later!"
    }


}
```

About its corresponding mainstoryboard:
[image]

I already make it as `Lines:2`, but when Xcode runs it, its content still cannot be displayed in multiple line. 
[image]

What should I do ?

When I add its width and height constraints, setting its horizontal space to ride side, set lines number to 0, it becomes:
[image]

Comment: set your numberof lines =0

Comment: set the height and width constraint of the label. Fixed width and flexible height should be able to serve your need. If you are adding thru code, you can use `\n` something like `"First line\nsecond line"`

Comment: Add a trailing constraint from the label to the parent view's right ride

Comment: did you set the width and height in constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed width and flexible height should be able to serve your need.

Try something like in the image below.
[image]

If you are adding the label text thru code, you can use `\n` in the text to divide it into multiple lines. something like

`label.text = "First line\nsecond line"`

To add on,
you can specify label.numberOfLines = 0. It means numberOfLines is infinity

Answer (score 0):

Set the trailing constraint with constant value as 20 from the label to the parent view. Then only label's content width is limited within the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed flexible height with auto layout 
[image]